# Copying rich text from the property of one object to another

Tags: applescript, omnifocus

I'm trying to use AppleScript to find existing OmniFocus tasks and attach projects and contexts based on certain rules.  This is working except that:

When I create the new task I'm trying to copy the `note` property directly.  In the dictionary for OmniFocus it says that the `note` property is "rich text", but in the new task it seems to have become plain text (particularly, links in the text which I would like to remain are going away, but there is other style which is disappearing)

```
on set_project_and_context(the_task, the_project, the_context)
    tell application "OmniFocus"
        tell front document
            set task_name to name of the_task
            set task_note to note of the_task
            set new_text to task_name & " ::" & the_project & " @" & the_context
            set new_tasks to (parse tasks into with transport text new_text with as single task)
            set new_task to item 1 of new_tasks
            set due date of new_task to missing value
            set note of new_task to task_note # <- HERE IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO COPY THE NOTE
            delete the_task
        end tell
    end tell
end set_project_and_context
```

I'm an AppleScript newbie, so any help is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this problem a bit unintuitively by creating the new task and assigning it's project and context to the existing task so that I don't need to re-create the note.  There are probably better ways to fetch the project and context, though I couldn't find a better way to do it which involved finding nested projects / contexts

```
on set_project_and_context(the_task, project_text, context_text)
    tell application "OmniFocus"
        tell front document
            set task_name to name of the_task
            set new_text to task_name & " ::" & project_text & " @" & context_text
            set new_tasks to (parse tasks into with transport text new_text with as single task)
            set new_task to item 1 of new_tasks

            set context of the_task to context of new_task
            set the_project to containing project of new_task
            set project_name to name of the_project
            move the_task to end of tasks of the_project
            delete new_task
        end tell
    end tell
end set_project_and_context
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy the note property directly because the new note would be plain text without all the styles and links.
To preserve formatting, you need to set the `style` property of every paragraph of the `note` property. I added a handler to set it.

Maybe this helps.

Code:

```
on set_project_and_context(the_task, the_project, the_context)
    tell application "OmniFocus"
        tell document 1
            set task_name to name of the_task
            set task_note to note of the_task
            set new_text to task_name & " ::" & the_project & " @" & the_context
            set new_tasks to (parse tasks into it with transport text new_text with as single task)
            set new_task to item 1 of new_tasks
            set due date of new_task to missing value
            my SetNote(the_task, new_task) -- NEW HANDLER
            delete the_task
        end tell
    end tell
end set_project_and_context

on SetNote(old_task, new_task)
    using terms from application "OmniFocus"
        set text of note of new_task to text of note of old_task
        set lst_paragraphs to (every paragraph of note of old_task)
        repeat with i from 1 to count lst_paragraphs
            set style of paragraph i of note of new_task to (style of paragraph i of note of old_task)
        end repeat
    end using terms from
end SetNote
```

Comment: Thanks for this, though unfortunately it wasn't working for me when there was style (like a line) in the middle of the paragraph.  I changed `paragraph` to `word`, which did work, but looked weird and was slow.  I actually came up with a fundamentally better approach which I'll share as another answer

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript itself doesn’t understand styled text, and there isn’t a standard way for apps to return text with style information attached, so:

```
set task_note to note of the_task
```

returns plain text only.

You need to tell the application to copy the rich text directly from one property to the other:

```
set note of new_task to note of the_task
```

Whether or not that command works will depend on how well the app’s scripting support is implemented; you just have to try it and see.

Comment: When I try that I get `OmniFocus got an error: Wrong type for note.  Should be text or rich text, "OSPropertyScriptText"`.  Is that maybe because OmniFocus' scripting support isn't good?

Comment: I don't have a copy of OF to play with here so am guessing the syntax. Omni have good user support & forums, so try asking there first. Otherwise, experiment. Try `set text of note of new_task to text of note of the_task`, `set text of note of new_task to note of the_task`, and any other variations you can think of to see if you can get it to produce the desired result. Sloppy poorly-specced behaviors and frustratingly incomplete documentation are standard "features" of most "AppleScriptable" apps; sometimes you just have to poke it with a stick in hopes of stumbling over something that works.

Comment: Yeah, I've experienced a bit of that so far ;) . Thanks!